# Nodejitsu while while starting node.js app

Tags: node.js, nodejitsu

I am very new to `node.js`, I just followed the steps to create a simple node.js application. [Here it is on github](https://github.com/ysfkel/test)

I ran the command `jitsu deploy` from the terminal to deploy it on `nodejitsu`, however I got this error right here, please any help on what could be wrong with code files? 
    [Here is the code on git hub](https://github.com/ysfkel/test)

Here is the error that is appearing:

```
prompt: Is this ok?:  (yes) yes
info:    Creating snapshot 0.0.0-5
info     Uploading: [=============================] 100%
info:    Updating app test
info:    Activating snapshot 0.0.0-5 for test
info:    Starting app test
error:   Error running command deploy
error:   Nodejitsu Error (500): Internal Server Error
error:   There was an error while attempting to deploy the app
error:
error:   Error spawning drone
error:   Script took too long to listen on a socket
error:
error:   This type of error is usually a user error.
error:   Error output from Haibu:
error:
error:   Error: Error spawning drone
error:       at Object.onTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/root/haibu-orchestra/node_mod
ules/haibu/lib/haibu/core/spawner.js:396:15)
error:       at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
help:    For help with this error contact Nodejitsu Support:
help:      webchat: <http://webchat.nodejitsu.com/>
help:          irc: <irc://chat.freenode.net/#nodejitsu>
help:        email: <support@nodejitsu.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're server.js is exporting a function, but that doesn't get run. Just the body of your `start` function as top-level code directly inside the server.js module so that it executes when nodejitsu starts your application.

Comment: His export is being called in `index.js` file, Peter. His `scripts.start` is `node index.js`, not `node server.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejitsu is very picky about how quick your deployments listen on the system. There is a certain time frame between the start of deployment and end of deployment before your deployment is considered a failure. When it doesn't listen on a port for so long, it ends up giving you this error.

Rather than using your current `start` function, why don't you try creating your HTTP socket in `index.js` and then passing it into your `start` function as well, since you're already passing routes and `handle` to it?

For example, in `index.js`:

```
var http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer().listen(8080);

start(server, router.route, handle);
```

Then, rather than using `http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080)` in your `server.js` file, you can use something like:

```
var start = function (server, route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    /* Your request stuff here */
  }
  server.on('request', onRequest);
};
```

This would most likely solve the whole problem.